# Is it possible to exploit a server using an C library with a vulnerability?

Tags: buffer-overflow, curl

A server has an old **libcurl** with the vulnerability [CVE-2013-2174](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-2174/). As the [documentation says](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20130622.html):

> it unlikely that programs allow user-provided strings unfiltered into
>   this function.

My question is: If this library is set in root mode (but local user can execute), can someone write a C program  to elevate the privileges to root?

Edit

I mean the permission is: `-rwxr-xr-x` so the root own it, but user can read and execute it.

Comment: What do you mean by "if this library is set in root mode"?

Comment: @grc I mean the permission is set as `-rwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If this library is set in root mode (but local user can execute), can someone write a C program to elevate the privileges to root?

I'm assuming that you mean that the library is owned by root and can only modified by root but that a non-privileged user can use this library inside its own program.

It actually does not matter who owns a library as long as the non-privileged user who is trying to use it can read it. In this case the library is loaded into the process started by the non-privileged user and is executed in the context of this user, i.e. only with the permissions of the user and not with root permissions even though the library itself might be owned by root. That means that no privilege escalation is possible this way.

Comment: This make sense.